# How do I define __str__() method in a model which has a Foreign Key of User model and get the values of fields in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have below model in my Django app and it has a Foreign Key of Django's default User Model with a `__str__()` method.

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}'
```

I want to show the subject name in the Admin Panel, when we open the Subjects Model/Table in the Admin Panel. Suppose that if we have a user with username 'khubi' and he has two subjects, then the Admin Panel just shows the username of the user that is 'khubi' instead of showing the subject's names. Below is the screenshot:

[image: subject.png]

I have tried to put this:

```
return f'{self.user.username.subject}'
```

But it gives the error that `'str' object has no attribute 'subject'`

and I have tried it as well:

```
return f'{self.user.subject}'
```

and it gives me the error `'User' object has no attribute 'subject'`

How can I get the name of the subject in the `__str__()` method and anywhere outside as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call `self.subject` for subject.

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.subject, self.user.username)
```

The given code will return **some_subject (khubi)**

Comment: and how will I get the name of the some subject of a specific user outside of this model, let's say in any template when working with forms?

Comment: Thank you so much @Hisham___Pak it worked. Please can you tell me the answer of question, I asked in above comment?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I have another model named `Detail(models.Model)` which has OneToOneFiled() as `subject = models.OneToOneField(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` for the Subject() model and Foreign Key for User() Model as `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` with some other fields like `mid_marks`, `final_marks` etc. What should I do if I want to get the detail of a subject (let's say 'Math') of the user 'khubi'?

Answer (score 0):

```
return f'{self.subject}'
```

is your correct way of access to the field `subject`, because `self.user.subject` is not part of the users fields. Maybe you should add a `related_name` to your field definition in the user, like this:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                max_length=100, related_name='subjects')
    # ...
```

In that way you can access from the users to their submitted subjects just asking the user object for its subjects: `subjects = user.subjects` as the others field.

Comment: Thanks @Shanks, can you help me in another part as well? I have another model named `Detail(models.Model)` which has OneToOneFiled() as `subject = models.OneToOneField(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` for the Subject() model and Foreign Key for User() Model as `user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` with some other fields like `mid_marks`, `final_marks` etc. What should I do if I want to get the detail of a subject (let's say 'Math') of the user 'khubi'?